# Como renderizar un componente Livewire dentro de otro?

Tags: php, laravel, component, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo un componente Livewire llamado Template

en este componente tengo esto...

```
<div>
<button wire:click="changeView('views.home')">Home</button>
<button wire:click="changeView('views.register')">Register</button>
<button wire:click="changeView('views.sale')">Sale</button>
{{$view}}
@livewire($view)
</div>
```

y en su logica tiene esto

```
class NewTemplate extends Component
{

public $view = "views.home";

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.new-template');
}

public function changeView($view){
    $this->view = $view;
}
}
```

Cada boton deberia cambiar la interface que se esta viendo (Como en una SPA) pero por algun motivo no esta funcionando, osea, si muestra el primer componente que estaria "Pre-cargado" (el home), pero cuando doy click simplemente no cambia el componente aunque el valor si cambia porque en la variable veo que cambia. Se que algo debe estar mal, pero no se que...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `$this->mount();` al final del método `changeView`, esto hará que tu componente `livewire` cambie nuevamente

#### NewTemplate.php

```
class NewTemplate extends Component
{

    public $view = "views.home";

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.new-template');
    }

    public function changeView($view){
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->mount();
    }
}
```

##### Edición:

Yo anteriormente lo he realizado utilizando condicionales y colocando dentro `@livewir`e o `@include`

#### new-template.blade.php

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="changeView('views.home')">Home</button>
    <button wire:click="changeView('views.register')">Register</button>
    <button wire:click="changeView('views.sale')">Sale</button>
    {{$view}}

    @if($view=='views.home')
    @livewire('views.home')
    @endif

    @if($view=='views.register')
    @livewire('views.register')
    @endif

    @if($view=='views.sale')
    @livewire('views.sale')
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: No funcionó, la variable cambia, pero no se renderiza el componente hijo

Comment: Agregue una edición a ver si eso te funciona

Comment: funcionó, lo extraño es que recuerdo haber usado un switch para hacer lo mismo y no funcionó.

Comment: Creo que es algo muy especifico sobre como Livewire renderiza los componentes, diria que la opcion más optima seria como lo tenias antes (aunque no se exactamente porque Livewire no renderiza en ese caso) pero creo que podrias encontrar una forma a partir de estos if para que sea más reutilizable y no abarque tanto código por si quieres agregar más vistas